# Dummy variable if it is in certain states

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dummy variable that is equal to 1 if it is in certain states.

My code is not working and I don't see the dummy variable being generated. any help would be appreciated.

```
as.integer(df2$physicaladdress.stateorprovincecode %in% 
             c("NJ", "NC", "PA", "RI", "WA", "DE", "GA", "HI", 
               "ID", "MD", "MT", "NM", "SC", "TX", "UT", "LA", "OH"))
```

In the console for I receive this but no variable is generated in the dataframe with the dummy variable.

```
[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  [25] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
  [49] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
  [73] 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
  [97] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [121] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 [145] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
 [169] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [193] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
 [217] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [241] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 [265] 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
 [289] 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 [313] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
 [337] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
 [361] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
 [385] 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
 [409] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
 [433] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 [457] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
 [481] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
 [505] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
 [529] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
 [553] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 [577] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
 [601] 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
 [625] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
 [649] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 [673] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
 [697] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 [721] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
 [745] 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
 [769] 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
 [793] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
 [817] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 [841] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
 [865] 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
 [889] 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
 [913] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [937] 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
 [961] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
 [985] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 547604 entries ]
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example:  [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: This should work, so could you give more details on what doesn't exactly work? See the link by @PaulS for examples/instruction on how to improve your question.

Comment: @PaulS thank you I have made updates to include the output I receive in console.

Comment: @Jaap I have udpated my question to show what is the outcome and what I am looking for.

Comment: The reason that you see no new variable in your dataframe is that you assign the result to a new variable. Your code shoulde be `df2$dummy <- as.integer(df2$physicaladdress.stateorprovincecode %in% c("NJ", "NC", "PA", "RI", "WA", "DE", "GA", "HI", "ID", "MD", "MT", "NM", "SC", "TX", "UT", "LA", "OH"))`